# Why does the Shield Hero manga have the qualifier "The Manga Companion"?

Tags: manga-production, the-rising-of-the-shield-hero

I was looking for manga adaptations of the *Rising of the Shield Hero* story and noticed something odd. Or at least something I haven't run into before.

The tittle of the manga was often appended with the qualifier "The Manga Companion", like on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935548700). I also saw the following phrase repeated some some stores:

> This is the Manga companion to the Ultimate Light novel series.

What does the "companion" qualifier mean in this context?
Is it common for a manga adaptation of a light novel to have this qualifier?
Does it imply that the manga isn't intended to sand on its own, or am I just reading too much into the word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, this was done by the publisher to prevent confusion, by indicating that it is the Manga companion to the original light novel.

Currently the light novel is sold under the same name, without the appended "The Manga Companion" which given the similar covers might lead to people buying the light novel when they intended to buy the manga, and vice versa.

As to why they chose "The Manga Companion" specifically over just "manga", I wouldn't know. Only *One Peace Books* would be able to tell us that.

Comment: Yeah, having "The Manga _Companion_" over just "Da Manga" is what's throwing me off. I might even reach out to the publisher about this.

Comment: @DJPirtu The word companion just means that it's not the original.  If it was called just the "The Rising of the Shield Hero Manga" you might mistakenly assume it was the original source material.